# Split write permission into append and delete permission

Tags: permissions, authorization

I'm writing a small authorization systems which has *read, write, execute, append* and *delete* permissions. If someone can write he can obviously also delete and append, so delete and append are part of write. I think all write operations could be expressed as append and delete and wonder if there would be any reason to distinguish between write and delete+append.

So the question is: Do you know any reason to distinguish between delete+append and write?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any. You might want to read up on how different operating systems implement [file permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions).

One other thing you might consider is whether write permissions also include read permissions.  It might make sense to do so in your case, but you might also consider a case where you want to create a "drop box" where someone can write a file but not be able to subsequently read it.